# Event Log giving Type Mismatch & Incorrect Syntax errors due to Excel Spreadsheet Export in Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp-classic, export-to-excel

thanks again for being here!

We have been having this issue for a while but never spent the time to address it.

When we print a page as an excel file through:

`Response.ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"`

We get a download window, as we should, in order to receive the resulting file.

If I save the file rather than open it, my server Event Logs show no error.

When the Open option is chosen, a loading bar appears.

This loading bar seems to be re-querying the page/re-running the asp, because the error we receive boils down to a null variable used in a sql query that is requesting a querystring.

http://s13.postimage.org/5mmkubzlj/ss2.jpg

Do I need to change the method of exporting this data to excel? Is there something I'm missing that will allow Excel to see that the file has already completed processing? Very confused as to what to do here.

Thoughts? Experiences? Thanks again!

Comment: try setting the `Response.Content-Disposition` too.

Comment: What can you tell me about this? I have never used it.